# Confusion about definition of complete statistic

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics

In Jun Shao's Mathematical Statistics (pp. 110 second edition), we encounter the following definition.

A statistic $T(X)$ is said to be complete for $P\in \mathcal P$ if and only if for any Borel $f$, $E[f(T)] = 0$ for all $P\in \mathcal P$ implies $f=0$ almost surely $\mathcal P$, i.e. $P(f=0) = 1$ for all $P\in \mathcal P$.

My issue is that I don't see how we can make sense of the statement $P(f=0)$. In my mind, the setup is that we have a family of probability distributions $\mathcal P$ on $(\mathbb R^n,\mathcal B(\mathbb R^n))$ and $T: (\mathbb R^n,\mathcal B(\mathbb R^n)) \to (\mathbb R^p,\mathcal B(\mathbb R^p))$ is measurable. This forces $f:(\mathbb R^p,\mathcal B(\mathbb R^p))\to (\mathbb R,\mathcal B(\mathbb R))$. But then what does it mean $P(f=0)$? This only makes sense if $P$ is the push forward measure of $T$, which it isn't. Maybe it is $P(f(T) = 0)=1$?

Am I interpreting something wrong or is the definition wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the literature (really just a google search) suggests it should be $P(f(T) = 0)=1$.